# Export to CSV in Python from JSON for loop

Tags: python, json, csv, export

How do I fix my formatting.

I know how to get the header and can also get the data exported in json format out to file.

My problem is each column needs to have the item index for each line.

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

```
f = open("export-results.csv", "a", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f)
header = 'Device Name', 'Operating System', 'IP Address'
for item in data:
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(item['name'])
    writer.writerow(item['os_version_and_architecture'])
    writer.writerow(item['last_ip_address'])
f.close()
```

Each column to have the value in full formatting and chosen from the ITEM list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()` to get index of the row. For example:

```py
with open("export-results.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    header = "Index", "Device Name", "Operating System", "IP Address"

    # write header
    writer.writerow(header)

    # write rows with index (starting from 1)
    for idx, item in enumerate(data, 1):
        writer.writerow(
            [
                idx,
                item["name"],
                item["os_version_and_architecture"],
                item["last_ip_address"],
            ]
        )
```

---

EDIT: Without the index:

```py
with open("export-results.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    header = "Device Name", "Operating System", "IP Address"

    # write header
    writer.writerow(header)

    # write rows
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow(
            [
                item["name"],
                item["os_version_and_architecture"],
                item["last_ip_address"],
            ]
        )
```

Comment: Thanks this is great is it also possible to remove the index as a column or is this needed?

Comment: @StephenMcFall Of course, you can remove it. Just alter the `header` (remove the `Index`) and don't use `enumerate()`. I've updated my answer.